# Como resolver o erro "'int' object is not subscriptable"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de ajuda na def abaixo, o erro aparece como:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
def editar(mercadoria):  
    print("\nEditar mercadoria: \n")     
    produto = input("\nDigite o produto a ser editado:")  
    marca = input("\nDigite a marca do produto:")  

 for i in range(len(mercadoria)):  

 if produto == i["produto"] and marca == i["marca"]:  
        print("\nAbaixo, digite os NOVOS dados.")  
        mercadoria[i]["produto"] = input("\nDigite o nome do produto:")  
        mercadoria[i]["marca"] = input("\nDigite a marca:")  
        mercadoria[i]["preço"] = input("\nDigite o preço unitário:")  
        mercadoria[i]["quantidade"] = input("\nDigite a quantidade recebida:")  
        print("\nDados atualizados com sucesso!")
```

Comment: range retorna uma sequencia de inteiros, logo não ha como vc pegar uma posição dentro de um inteiro, i['produto']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro no seu código está sendo gerado porque o range retorna números inteiros. Logo você não pode obter a posição de algo nele e acaba gerando este erro.

Se você por acaso `mercadoria` for uma lista de dicionários ou qualquer outra coisa do tipo, você pode percorre-la desta forma:

```
 for i in mercadoria:
```

Desta forma não será gerado o erro.

Veja um exemplo simples abaixo de como as duas formas de `for loop` funcionam:

```
lista = ["pizza","lasanha","abacaxi","macarronada","biscoito"]

for i in range(len(lista)):
    print(i)

"""
Output:

0
1
2
3
4
"""

for i in lista:
    print(i)

"""
Output:

pizza
lasanha
abacaxi
macarronada
biscoito
"""
```